# Matching an instance most specific class in python

Tags: python, python-3.10

Lets say I have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`, `C` extends `B`, and `B` extends `A`.

```
@dataclass
class A:
    value: int

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass
```

In python 3.10 with the match feature introduced, I thought about changing isinstance-elif statements into a match-case statement. But i cant quite find the right syntax for it...

What I have tried so far...

```
match instance.__class__.__name__:
    case A.__name__:
        print('A')
    case B.__name__:
        print('B')
```

But what if two classes have the same `__name__` prop. Here even a `C` instance wont match any case.

Next syntax... this one is better

```
match instance:
    case A():
        print('A')
    case B():
        print('B')
```

This syntax works quite good, except that a `B` instance will match the first case, so I will need to topologyically sort the classes in my match-case statement.

Additional Question: Is this a special syntax where no params are needed ?

Question: What other choices do I have ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the parent of the instance you could do `instance.__class__.__bases__[0]` `__bases__` returns a tuple with the parent classess.

---

I tried that with the match statement but get the following warning:

```
match instance.__class__.__bases__[0]:
    case A:  # makes remaining clause unreachable
        print('A')
    case ...
```

Using `A().__class__` instead, yields yet another error.. *"Unexpected tokens"*

---

Nevertheless, `C().__class__.__bases__[0] == B` yields True.